# Why i can't enable crash report on Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I register on firebase and i followed the steps from Android studio everything looks fine, i found my app in firebase console and some stats for my app.

But the most important is to see when my app crash and i also want to get some info from variables before the crash, so from Android Studio again i add the the crash report but nothing happened, then i follow the steps on the site...still nothing.

When my app runs the test crash lines examples from firebase site it crashes also at firebase console at the crash section nothigh is appeared except the install in fabric & install in firebase options

Comment: `so from Android Studio again i add the the crash report` tell us how you did this, you maybe missing something!

Comment: Do you have uploaded your app to the PlayStore? I have noticed that recently app crashes do not register in Firebase anymore, but in the Developer Console. Maybe Google updated the crash reporting and now consumes all crash-events before Firebase can report them.

Comment: @AtefHares Tools>Firebase>setup Firebase crash reporting... and i did what its says there, i have now (ok) Connected, (ok) Dependencies set up correctly. but when i add the code "FirebaseCrash.log("Activity created");" my app crashes

Comment: @Vacutainer Yes it was already on playstore and i can see at Developer Console the chrashes yes but still i want to create a message before the crash an send it somehow... ppl here told me that firebase can do this. I dont know if Play Console is showing all Crashes??

Comment: Please share the LogCat output for the crash.

Comment: @Vacutainer well i found these two: 1) Firebase API initialization failure 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
bla bla 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ...
and
2)AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process:(...), PID: (...)
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: (....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to Update everything on Android Studio and make use of latest vesions.